# iOS: Getting NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML working?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsattributedstring

I am trying to get NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML working but the project doesn't ever build for me, there are errors.  Also, there is no documentation that I can find that shows what files need to be imported and how exactly to use it with HTML.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

```
#import <CoreText/CoreText.h>
```

and
CoreText.framework